# Использование компонента WebView для полного экрана

Tags: java, webview, android-webview

Создал минималистичный браузер без всяких либо внедрений для улучшения качества. Решил я зайти на ютуб через мой браузер и наживая на кнопку "Во весь экран" ничего не происходит, хоть анимация нажатия кнопки была. То есть я не могу посмотреть видео со всех сайтов в которых присутствует кнопка для отображения в полный экран. Вот код экрана:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ProgressBar progressBar;
    EditText inputUrl;
    WebView webView;
    ImageButton sendButton, forwardButton, backButton, refreshButton;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        inputUrl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        sendButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
        forwardButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.forwardButton);
        backButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.backButton);
        refreshButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.refreshButton);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
                if(newProgress==100)
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                else
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        WebSettings webset = webView.getSettings();
        webset.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webset.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String url = inputUrl.getText().toString();

                if(url.contains("http://")||url.contains("https://")){
                    return;

                }
                else if(url.contains(" ")||url.contains("")){
                    url = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+url;
                }
                else if(url.contains(".")&&!url.contains(" ")){
                    url = "http://"+url;
                }


                webView.loadUrl(url);
                url = webView.getOriginalUrl();
                inputUrl.setText(webView.getOriginalUrl());
                inputUrl.setText(webView.getUrl());


                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(webView.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        });

        forwardButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (webView.canGoForward())
                    webView.goForward();
                    inputUrl.setCursorVisible(false);
                    inputUrl.clearComposingText();
                    inputUrl.clearFocus();
                    inputUrl.clearAnimation();
            }
        });

        backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (webView.canGoBack())
                    webView.goBack();
                inputUrl.setCursorVisible(false);
                inputUrl.clearComposingText();
                inputUrl.clearFocus();
                inputUrl.clearAnimation();

            }
        });

        refreshButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                webView.reload();
                inputUrl.setCursorVisible(false);
                inputUrl.clearComposingText();
                inputUrl.clearFocus();
                inputUrl.clearAnimation();
            }
        });
        inputUrl.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                inputUrl.selectAll();

                return false;
            }
        });
        if(inputUrl.isLongClickable()||inputUrl.isClickable()){
            inputUrl.selectAll();
        }


    }
```

Вот код клиента:

```java
public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Как мы видим JS разрешён и я в недоумении почему нельзя смотреть видео в полный экран

Answer (score 0):

Решается такая проблема добавлением кастомного клиента:

```
private class MyChrome extends WebChromeClient {

        private View mCustomView;
        private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback;
        protected FrameLayout mFullscreenContainer;
        private int mOriginalOrientation;
        private int mOriginalSystemUiVisibility;

        MyChrome() {}

        public Bitmap getDefaultVideoPoster()
        {
            if (mCustomView == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), 2130837573);
        }

        public void onHideCustomView()
        {
            ((FrameLayout)getWindow().getDecorView()).removeView(this.mCustomView);
            this.mCustomView = null;
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(this.mOriginalSystemUiVisibility);
            setRequestedOrientation(this.mOriginalOrientation);
            this.mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
            this.mCustomViewCallback = null;
        }

        public void onShowCustomView(View paramView, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback paramCustomViewCallback)
        {
            if (this.mCustomView != null)
            {
                onHideCustomView();
                return;
            }
            this.mCustomView = paramView;
            this.mOriginalSystemUiVisibility = getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
            this.mOriginalOrientation = getRequestedOrientation();
            this.mCustomViewCallback = paramCustomViewCallback;
            ((FrameLayout)getWindow().getDecorView()).addView(this.mCustomView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -1));
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(3846 | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
        }
    }
```

вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768837/playing-html5-video-on-fullscreen-in-android-webview/56186877#56186877) более подробно описано в чем именно проблема и вот такая проблема упоминается [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62573334/android-webview-fullscreen-on-videos-not-working)

Comment: Как я понимаю сдесь используется клиент хрома, нельзя так с наследством `WebViewClient `

Comment: для воспроизведения видео лучше использовать клиент хрома, так как он обладает более полным функционалом для работы с JS. WebViewClient обладает только базовыми в которые проигрывание видео очевидно входит неполностью

Comment: более подробно можно почитать здесь - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835556/whats-the-difference-between-setwebviewclient-vs-setwebchromeclient

Comment: Под 4.0 андроид не потянет код)